# Not able to subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

i have create a method getProducts but not able to subscribe the response and getting the below error.

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<any>'
```

service file

```
   public cartItemList :any = [];
   public productsList  = new BehaviorSubject<any>([])
   constructor() { }
   
   getProducts(){
      return this.productsList.asObservable;
   }
```

component.ts file

```
  public totalItem:Number = 0;
  constructor(private cartService:CartService){}
  ngOnInit():void{
    this.cartService.getProducts()
    .subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.totalItem =res.length;})
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

'asObservable' is a method not a property, so it´s just to add () and it should work.

```
getProducts(){
 return this.productsList.asObservable;
}
```

should turn into:

```
getProducts(){
 return this.productsList.asObservable();
}
```